# Unable to consume OpenShift REST API in C#.net

Tags: api, rest, openshift, consuming

I want to know how can I consume OpenShift Rest API into C#.net based application. I have gone through URL 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/pdf/REST_API_Guide/OpenShift_Online-2.0-REST_API_Guide-en-US.pdf, in this there mentioned example for Ruby, Python and cRUL. but not mentioned for .Net. so I have created sample application for consuming this api. 
below is the code -

```
string URL = "https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/xml;";
 try
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
            string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.Out.WriteLine(response);
            responseReader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("-----------------");
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

While executing above code I am getting following error -
"The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable."

Please let me where I am doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance
Jyoti

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong HTTP header. `ContentType` is used for POST/PUT operations to tell server what to expect. When you GET a resource you must specify an `Accept` header.

```
request.Accept = "application/xml";
```